# Autolayout for uitableviewcell using xcode 6

Tags: uitableview, xcode6, ios-autolayout

My app is designed for iPad landscape initially using xcode 6. Currently it is to be rendered to portrait version of iPad too. How to achieve the same using autolayout for the below image.

Design using xib:
[image: UITableViewCell's content]

The above image is the cell contents of a uitableviewcell. Tried providing constrains.

After providing constrains, i got the result as

1. In Landscape
   [image: Runtime Result in Landscape]
2. In Portrait
   [image: Runtime Result in Portrait]

I want to see all my labels to get into to my screen. If the width exceeds the labels will get multiline and autoheight calculation had been also implemented in the tableview.

The problem is i'm unable to get the labels fit on to the screen with fixed horizontal spacing as shown in design time.

I need help to render design for the tableviewcell.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to provide the **width** of these labels with **aspect ratio** and also specify the **width between the labels** as **fixed**(10 or 20).
This might work.